# What is wrong with my Postfix config for Linux mail command?

Tags: bash, cron, postfix-mta

EDIT: Thank you to Cyrus for the solution.  The issue was with my cron jobs not postfix.
Instead of:

```
*/5 * * * * | /usr/bin/mail -s 'Scheduled Email' user@gmail.com
```

Jobs need to be scheduled like:

```
*/5 * * * * echo "Message body" | /usr/bin/mail -s 'Scheduled Email' user@gmail.com
```

I've written a Bash script which allows the user to schedule a cron job for sending emails.  I am using sharutils uuencode and mailutils mail.

The mail command works fine from command line, I receive the email on my gmail account and in the maillog I can see the mail being sent.  The from is user@machineName and the to is name@gmail.com.  However when one of my scheduled cron jobs tries to send using the mail command I run into problems.

Rather than the from and to both being the same as they were when I ran via command line, the maillog now shows from=<> and to=.  Both my mail and uuencode are located in /usr/bin and in my script I give the full path when calling them.

Here is the config part of my Postfix main.cf

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated  defer_unauth_destination  
myhostname = hostname.example.com  
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases  
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases  
mydestination =   
relayhost =   
myorigin = $mydomain  
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128  
mailbox_size_limit = 0
```

In my crontab jobs from my script show up like this.

```
*/5 * * * * | /usr/bin/mail -s 'Scheduled Email' user@gmail.com  
*/15 * * * * | /usr/bin/mail -s 'Scheduled Email' user@gmail.com
```

All I want to be able to do is send out from a dummy address.  I don't need authentication, I don't need to make it send from a real email address.  I just need the cronjob to send properly the same way mail does when I run it standalone from command line.  What part of my config do I need to change?

Thanks!

Comment: @Cyrus - updated OP to show how cronjobs from my script look in crontab

Comment: Which user runs this cronjob? Please add name and version of your operating system. Which packet originates /usr/bin/mail?

Comment: @Cyrus it runs within a normal user account, not root, and this is on Linux Mint 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
*/5 * * * * echo "Hello, this is the body." | /usr/bin/mail -s 'Scheduled Email' name@gmail.com'.
```

Comment: For some reason that works, thank you!  Do you have any idea why not having a body would make the cron job use the wrong to and from fields?

Comment: Your syntax was incorrect. Correct: `command | command` or only `command`. Feel free to try: `*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/mail -s 'Scheduled Email' name@gmail.com'`. Maybe it works.